# Css menu / submenu issue related to z-index

Tags: html, css

I am having issues with my navigation bar CSS.
I want it to look like : 
http://i39.tinypic.com/28is4uw.png

But this is what I'm getting: 
http://i40.tinypic.com/akecl5.png

The only way for me to make it work like that is by using:

```
.under-menu { position: relative;  z-index:999; }
```

but this kills the `submenu links`.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Code is here: http://cssdesk.com/gejyB
OR : http://cssdeck.com/labs/vzg4njme

Comment: under-menu [ position: absolute;  z-index:999;]

Comment: @user2216267 - position absolute didnt work at all. it actually hides it.

Comment: Specify more height to undermenu and less z-index to it !

Comment: this makes the link invalid

Comment: The rieht thing is to put the submenu under the menu but it wil not work because the [background image](http://i42.tinypic.com/huhev8.png) of the menu is not transparent at the bot.

Comment: Ok you are having a background to the parent element, and you are trying to hide the child behind it's parent, that's a hard quest my friend. :) Even if do make it, the white waves are not transparent, and they will overlay the dropdown with those gray space between each wave. So you should make the white wave absolute and positioned it at the bottom of the navigation minus it's height.

Comment: Image is transparent. Check the "third try" and you'll see the issue im having. please let me know. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution, but at least some if we want to support IE, if not just adding

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Will fix the problem. This demo doesn't include pointer-events.

Here is a demo:
[CSSDesk](http://cssdesk.com/RpZkY)

In summary, I added the wave background inside the dropdown (in the li where the link and the drop ul is), and the effect is almost the same with your second try, with the only differents that I mask the top part of the drop down with the background that I added in the LI. 
You will see that the wave background shadow becomes ticker, since the other background is still there (you can hide it with JS then it will become better, but since this is only a html/css topic I dind't add any JS )

So when you hover on the LI element the overlay background shows. 
So that overlay background should be added for each li with drop-down. (like I said not a perfect solution)